# Creating temp tables in ColdFusion (copying records without duplicate id)

Tags: coldfusion-8

I know, I know, this is older than your grandma but I can't figure out for the life of me why I can execute the following query on a phpmyadmin but not in a `cfquery` tag.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ENGINE=MEMORY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I can't make more than one query per cfquery tag. Essentially this is for copying records in MySQL with ColdFusion. If someone can simplify this further I'd appreciate it.

```
  <cfquery datasource="#request.datasource#">
      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp
  </cfquery>
  <cfquery result="copied" datasource="#request.datasource#">
      CREATE TABLE temp ENGINE=MEMORY
      SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id= <cfqueryparam value="#id_im_looking_for#">
  </cfquery>

  <cfquery result="copied" datasource="#request.datasource#">
    INSERT INTO mytable SELECT NULL, name, description, NOW() FROM temp
  </cfquery>

  <cfquery datasource="#request.datasource#">
    DROP TABLE temp
  </cfquery>
```

A little verbose to me.

Comment: That much logic is usually better wrapped in a stored procedure. If you must use separate queries, keep in mind temp tables are session based (not the same as a CF session). So the queries should be wrapped in a cftransaction to *ensure* you maintain the same session or db connection. Though [as I mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39987760/104223), it does not seem like a temp table is even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), the execution of multiple statements is disabled by default, for security reasons. It can be enabled in your DSN by adding `allowMultiQueries=true` to the DSN "Connection Settings". Just be aware that enabling this setting will expose the database to certain forms of sql injection. So be sure to use `cfqueryparam` on ALL query parameters.

> ***allowMultiQueries***
>
> Allow the use of ';' to delimit multiple
> queries during one statement (true/false), defaults to 'false'

Having said that, not sure why you need a temp table. A simple INSERT / SELECT should do the trick. There is no reason you cannot insert and select from the same table. Not unless the end result would violate a constraint.

```
 INSERT INTO mytable ( Name, Description, SomeDateCol )
 SELECT name, description, NOW() 
 FROM   mytable 
 WHERE  id = <cfqueryparam value="#id_im_looking_for#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_YourTypeHere">
```